# Sql server spatial indexes stored procedure performance tuning

Tags: sql-server

Hi all I am doing a performance tuning on one of my stored procedure which has update statement:

```
UPDATE e
        SET
            LNG_PROP  = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(A.geom.STPointN(A.geom.STNumPoints()/2).ToString(), 4326).Long
            ,LAT_PROP = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(A.geom.STPointN(A.geom.STNumPoints()/2).ToString(), 4326).Lat
        FROM
            Exports.SpatialKey_MTG22 e           
            INNER JOIN dbo.Addresses A WITH (NOLOCK) ON  A.FullName = e.ADDR_STREET_PROP AND ((e.ADDR_NUMBER_PROP BETWEEN LFROMHN AND LTOHN OR e.ADDR_NUMBER_PROP BETWEEN RFROMHN AND RTOHN) OR (e.ADDR_NUMBER_PROP BETWEEN LTOHN AND LFROMHN OR e.ADDR_NUMBER_PROP BETWEEN RTOHN AND RFROMHN))
            INNER JOIN dbo.ZipCodes Z WITH (NOLOCK) ON Z.ZipCode = A.ZipL OR Z.ZipCode = A.ZipR AND (Z.ZipCode = e.IC_PROP_ZIP OR (Z.State = e.IC_PROP_STATE AND Z.City = e.IC_PROP_CITY))
```

I tried modifying:

```
Select                     e.SpatialKey_MTG22_ID,e.AC_ACCOUNT_NAME,e.IC_PROP_ADDR_1,e.ADDR_NUMBER_PROP,e.ADDR_STREET_PROP,e.IC_PROP_CITY,e.IC_PROP_STATE,e.IC_PROP_ZIP
                     ,[LNG_PROP]  = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(e.geom.STPointN(e.geom.STNumPoints()/2).ToString(), 4326).Long
                     ,[LAT_PROP] = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(e.geom.STPointN(e.geom.STNumPoints()/2).ToString(), 4326).Lat
          FROM
       (
              SELECT e.*,A.geom,A.ZIPL,A.ZIPR
              FROM
                     Exports.SpatialKey_MTG22 e               
                     INNER JOIN dbo.Addresses A WITH (NOLOCK) 
                           ON  A.FullName = e.ADDR_STREET_PROP 
           WHERE
                     ((e.ADDR_NUMBER_PROP BETWEEN LFROMHN AND LTOHN OR e.ADDR_NUMBER_PROP BETWEEN RFROMHN AND RTOHN) 
                                         OR (e.ADDR_NUMBER_PROP BETWEEN LTOHN AND LFROMHN OR e.ADDR_NUMBER_PROP BETWEEN RTOHN AND RFROMHN))
       ) e
INNER JOIN dbo.ZipCodes Z WITH (NOLOCK) 
                           ON     (Z.ZipCode = e.ZipL OR Z.ZipCode = e.ZipR) 
                                  AND (Z.ZipCode = e.IC_PROP_ZIP OR (Z.State = e.IC_PROP_STATE AND Z.City = e.IC_PROP_CITY))
```

I have 26 million records in address table 
it still takes more than 1 hour to run.
Can anyone please help me on what changes can be made so that I can improve the performance.

Comment: Please indicate with your tags (by removing one) whether you use SQL Server or MySQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are different products. MySQL does not refer to Your SQL and SQL Server does not mean SQL that happens to be run on a server.

Comment: Do you know what indexes if any are on the table?

Comment: Are you trying to update 26 million rows in one shot? That's a lot for the transaction log to handle. Can you batch the update? That in and of itself may help.